# how to scale a div so its size is the same to image's size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` to which I append different images with different sizes.

How can I set its size to be the same with the image's size.

For example if the size of the image is `640*480` the `div` size is the same. If the next image is `1024*768` the `div` size automatically changes to `1024*768`

Thanks

Comment: You may need `display: block` on the img

Comment: Assuming you use JavaScript to append, you might also want to use JavaScript to set the height and width of the element. Not sure what's easier though.

Answer (score 1):

`div` is a block level element so will be full width, making it wider than the image.  To get around that you could add `div {float: left}` to your CSS.  Also, add `img {display: block}` to ensure the image fits flush in the div in terms of height

Comment: I made `float:left;` for the div and `img.setAttribute("display", "block");` and the div does not resize. If I make `overflow:auto` just for the div and nothing for the image , div resizes. But I want to also limit the width of the div to 900. If I add `max-width:940px;` and the image is too big, I see the half image. What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: I've made a jsfiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/bQpnP/1/.  Can you explain where yours is different / going wrong?

Comment: OK, thanks for the fiddle, makes things clear. One more thing to ask. `img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}`Resizes all the images of the page. How can I limit this to just the images of the specific div? Thanks again

Comment: You can target the div first using it's ID or class name and then the image, e.g. `div.img-holder img { display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; }`

Comment: Glad to help. If you could mark the answer as correct, that would help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
function loadBackground(img) {
  newBg =                       document.createElement('IMG');
  newBg.src =                   img;

  bgContainer =                 document.getElementById('background-container');
  bgContainer.appendChild(newBg);

  newBg.onload = function() {
    imgs =                      bgContainer.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
    bgContainer.style.width =   newBg.offsetWidth;
    bgContainer.style.height =  newBg.offsetHeight;
    bgContainer.removeChild(imgs[0]);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='background-container'>
  <img src='image0.jpg'>
</div>

<a href='javascript: loadBackground("image1.jpg");'>Image 1</a>
```